# HttpsURLConnection : Connection tmed out

Tags: java, linux, httpsurlconnection

I am trying to connect to a REST API URL (like https://xyz.abc.com/username=test&password=test)using Java from Linux. Below is the code.

```
        URL url = new URL(URL);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
        conn.connect();
```

I am facing Connection timed out issue while connecting to the URL.

```
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
```

I am not able to ping to xyz.abc.com as well. Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to ping that say the URL is not reachable from your host. Few other tests you can do is below :

1. install netcat (nc) and run below command :

$ nc -vz IPADDRESS PORT

If it is connected then Java program should work

2. Try using curl

$ curl -x URL

and see the result you are getting.

This mostly can be firewall issue. Do check with your network team also

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. How do I narrow it down to firewall issue?

Comment: use traceroute to ipaddress and see where it is blocking. That's the network device where the firewall is missing.